# Java web app with JSF - layered and moduled design with DI and no framework

Tags: java, jsf

Any comments? I tried to make my code modular and testable. I tried to make use of dependency injection without using any frameworks. All the classes are stateless, immutable and thread-safe (I think). I also tried to code to interfaces, not implementations.

**Utils**

```
package biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:26 PM
 */
public interface SakilaEntityManagerFactory {
    EntityManager getEntityManager();
    void closeFactory();
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 6:00 PM
 */
public class SakilaEntityManagerFactoryImpl implements SakilaEntityManagerFactory {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public SakilaEntityManagerFactoryImpl(String persistenceUnitName) {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        }
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void closeFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**Model Layer**

```
package biz.tugay.sakila.core.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:56 PM
 */
public abstract class BaseModelObject implements Serializable {
    protected int id;
    public abstract int getId();
    public abstract void setId(int id);
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:20 PM
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "actor")
public class Actor extends BaseModelObject {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Actor actor = (Actor) o;

        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(actor.firstname) : actor.firstname != null) return false;
        return lastname != null ? lastname.equals(actor.lastname) : actor.lastname == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**DAO Layer**
package biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao;

```
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.BaseModelObject;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:47 PM
 */
public interface BaseDao<Entity extends BaseModelObject> {
    EntityManager entityManager();
    Entity get(EntityManager entityManager, int id);
    List<Entity> getAll(EntityManager entityManager);
    void beginTransaction(EntityManager entityManager);
    void insertNew(EntityManager entityManager, Entity entity);
    void commit(EntityManager entityManager);
    void rollback(EntityManager entityManager);
    void flush(EntityManager entityManager);
    void close(EntityManager entityManager);
    void insertMultiple(EntityManager entityManager, Collection<Entity> actors);
    void remove(EntityManager entityManager, Entity e);
    void update(EntityManager entityManager, Entity e);
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.BaseModelObject;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils.SakilaEntityManagerFactory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:49 PM
 */
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<Entity extends BaseModelObject> implements BaseDao<Entity> {

    private final SakilaEntityManagerFactory sakilaEntityManagerFactory;
    protected final Class<Entity> clazz;

    public BaseDaoImpl(SakilaEntityManagerFactory sakilaEntityManagerFactory, Class<Entity> clazz) {
        this.sakilaEntityManagerFactory = sakilaEntityManagerFactory;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = sakilaEntityManagerFactory.getEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Entity get(EntityManager entityManager, int id) {
        final Entity entity = entityManager.find(clazz, id);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Entity> getAll(EntityManager entityManager) {
        final String modelName = clazz.getSimpleName();
        final String query = String.format("From %s", modelName);
        final TypedQuery<Entity> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, clazz);
        final List<Entity> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

    public void beginTransaction(EntityManager entityManager) {
        final EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertNew(EntityManager entityManager, Entity entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertMultiple(EntityManager entityManager, Collection<Entity> entityCollection) {
        for (Entity entity : entityCollection) {
            insertNew(entityManager, entity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(EntityManager entityManager, Entity entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(EntityManager entityManager, Entity entity) {
        final Entity t = get(entityManager, entity.getId());
        entityManager.remove(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    @Override
    public void flush(EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close(EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.Actor;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 6:44 PM
 */
public interface ActorDao extends BaseDao<Actor> {
    Collection<Actor> byLastname(EntityManager entityManager, String lastname);
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.Actor;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils.SakilaEntityManagerFactory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/13/2016
 * Time: 8:23 PM
 */
public class ActorDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Actor> implements ActorDao {

    public ActorDaoImpl(SakilaEntityManagerFactory sakilaEntityManagerFactory) {
        super(sakilaEntityManagerFactory, Actor.class);
    }

    /* Ignores case! */
    @Override
    public Collection<Actor> byLastname(EntityManager entityManager, String lastname) {
        final String query = "SELECT a FROM Actor a WHERE UPPER(a.lastname) = :lastname";
        final TypedQuery<Actor> byLastnameQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, clazz);
        byLastnameQuery.setParameter("lastname", lastname.toUpperCase());
        final Collection<Actor> byLastnameResultList = byLastnameQuery.getResultList();
        return byLastnameResultList;
    }
}
```

**Service Layer**
package biz.tugay.sakila.core.service;

```
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.BaseModelObject;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 4:42 PM
 */
public interface BaseService<Entity extends BaseModelObject> {
    Entity get(int id);
    List<Entity> getAll();
    void insertNew(Entity entity);
    void delete(Entity entity);
    void update(Entity entity);
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.service;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao.BaseDao;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.BaseModelObject;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 4:30 PM
 */
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<Dao extends BaseDao, Entity extends BaseModelObject> implements BaseService<Entity> {

    final Dao dao;

    public BaseServiceImpl(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Entity get(int id) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        final BaseModelObject object = dao.get(entityManager, id);
        dao.close(entityManager);
        return (Entity) object;
    }

    public final List<Entity> getAll() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        final List<Entity> all = dao.getAll(entityManager);
        dao.close(entityManager);
        return all;
    }

    public final void insertNew(final Entity entity) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        dao.insertNew(entityManager, entity);
        dao.beginTransaction(entityManager);
        dao.commit(entityManager);
        dao.close(entityManager);
    }

    public final void update(final Entity entity) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        dao.beginTransaction(entityManager);
        dao.update(entityManager, entity);
        dao.commit(entityManager);
        dao.close(entityManager);
    }

    public final void delete(final Entity entity) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        dao.beginTransaction(entityManager);
        dao.remove(entityManager, entity);
        dao.commit(entityManager);
        dao.close(entityManager);
    }
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.service;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.Actor;

import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 6:38 PM
 */
public interface ActorService extends BaseService<Actor> {
    Collection<Actor> byLastname(String lastname);
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.core.service;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao.ActorDao;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.Actor;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 4:04 PM
 */
public final class ActorServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<ActorDao, Actor> implements ActorService {

    public ActorServiceImpl(ActorDao actorDAO) {
        super(actorDAO);
    }

    @Override
    public final Collection<Actor> byLastname(final String lastname) {
        final EntityManager entityManager = dao.entityManager();
        final Collection<Actor> byLastname = dao.byLastname(entityManager, lastname);
        dao.close(entityManager);
        return byLastname;
    }
}
```

**Web Layer(JSF Managed Beans)**

```
package biz.tugay.sakila.web;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 9:52 PM
 */
public class BasePageBacking {

    protected <BeanClass> BeanClass getBean(String beanName, Class<BeanClass> clazz) {
        final ServletContext servletContext
                = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        final Object bean = servletContext.getAttribute(beanName);
        final BeanClass castBean = clazz.cast(bean);
        return castBean;
    }

    protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    }
}

package biz.tugay.sakila.web.actor;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.model.Actor;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.service.ActorService;
import biz.tugay.sakila.web.BaseFormBacking;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/15/2016
 * Time: 4:29 PM
 */

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class ActorFormBacking extends BaseFormBacking {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Actor actor;

    private final ActorService actorService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    // Invoked by JSF!
    public ActorFormBacking() {
        actorService = getBean("actorService", ActorService.class);
        actor = new Actor();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    // Invoked by JSF!
    public final void init() {
        final String actorId = getRequest().getParameter("actorId");
        if (actorId != null) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(actorId);
            actor = actorService.get(id);
        }
    }

    public final String insertNewActor() {
        actorService.insertNew(actor);
        return "actorInserted";
    }

    public final String updateActor(final int id) {
        actor.setId(id);
        actorService.update(actor);
        return "actorUpdated";
    }

    public final String deleteActor(Actor actor) {
        actorService.delete(actor);
        return "actorDeleted";
    }

    // For unit tests
    public ActorFormBacking(ActorService actorService) {
        this.actorService = actorService;
    }
}
```

**Initializing the application when the server starts:**

```
package biz.tugay.sakila.web.listener;

import biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao.ActorDao;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.dao.ActorDaoImpl;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.service.ActorService;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.service.ActorServiceImpl;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils.SakilaEntityManagerFactory;
import biz.tugay.sakila.core.utils.SakilaEntityManagerFactoryImpl;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 5:31 PM
 */

@WebListener
public class SakilaApplicationServletContextListenerImpl implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();

        final SakilaEntityManagerFactory sakilaEntityManagerFactory = new SakilaEntityManagerFactoryImpl("SakilaPU");
        servletContext.setAttribute("sakilaEntityManagerFactory", sakilaEntityManagerFactory);

        final ActorDao actorDao = new ActorDaoImpl(sakilaEntityManagerFactory);
        servletContext.setAttribute("actorDao", actorDao);

        final ActorService actorService = new ActorServiceImpl(actorDao);
        servletContext.setAttribute("actorService", actorService);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        final SakilaEntityManagerFactory sakilaEntityManagerFactory = (SakilaEntityManagerFactory) servletContext.getAttribute("sakilaEntityManagerFactory");
        sakilaEntityManagerFactory.closeFactory();
    }
}
```

The source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/koraytugay/sakila/tree/d28b7da3232553fcce855e874351fd81d5a17bcb).

Comment: I don't know why people up-voted this question, because it does not provide any description of what the problem is / what the code is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SakilaEntityManagerFactory` can extend `AutoClosable` instead of providing it's own `closeFactory()` method. By extending `AutoClosable` you can take advantage of sopport from IDEs and various static code analysis tools that will report leaked(unclosed) factories.
2. Your model does not really need to be `Serializable` as you do not use the native java serialization. Libraries like Gson,Jackson, etc do not rely on native java serialization and do not require objects to implement `Serializable`
3. Not a big issue, but seems "unnatural" to me. On every project I've worked, the base class names follow the pattern `<Name>Base`, but you are doing it in the opposite way `Base<Name>`. Example: BaseModelObject  should be ModelObjectBase
4. Do you really need DAOs ? If you take a look at your code you'll see that your daos just delegate directly to the `EntityManager`. Then instead of "dao.newInstance()" why don't you directly call `entityManager.persist()` ? DAOs can be used to hide the underlying implementation, but your DAOs leak that they are based on `EntityManager`. For simple CRUD uperations DAOs are unnecessary and just complicate the code.
5. Your DAO methods are misleading. `insertNew()` does not necessarily create a new entry at the database. If the passed entity is already a "managed object" `insertNew()` won't do anything! If the entity is not a managed object, but has non null @ID, then calling `persist()` (or actually on flush/transaction end) will throw `PersistenceException` if ther eis already an entry with that ID. the method `update()` suffers from simmilar issues. For more details read about `persist()`/`merge()` and how they work and what they do.
6. Instead of using some magic strings for attributes like "sakilaEntityManagerFactory" you can use the interface/class names: `SakilaEntityManagerFactory.class.getName()`
7. Either design for inheritance or explicitly forbid it. If it's (obviously) not an interface or an abstract/base class you should consider marking it as `final`. An exception can be the model objects, because some persistence libraries may not be able to instrument them if they are final.
8. The `SakilaApplicationServletContextListenerImpl` name is just terrible. Consider shorter and more descriptive name like "PersistenceServiceInitializer" or "PersistenceServiceLifecycle(Listener)", etc

Answer (score 1):

**Consider using proper Javadoc**

Instead of writing

```
/**
 * User: Koray Tugay (koray@tugay.biz)
 * Date: 9/14/2016
 * Time: 5:31 PM
 */
```

more canonical usage would be (for example):

```
/**
 * (Here, describe your class/interface.)
 *
 * @author Koray Tugay
 * @version 9/14/2016 5:31 PM
 */
```

**Using minor utilities**

In the **`Actor.java`**, you can rewrite a couple of methods more succintly (your code commented):

```
//    @Override
//    public boolean equals(Object o) {
//        if (this == o) return true;
//        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
//
//        Actor actor = (Actor) o;
//
//        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(actor.firstname) : actor.firstname != null) return false;
//        return lastname != null ? lastname.equals(actor.lastname) : actor.lastname == null;
//
//    }

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !getClass().equals(o.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }

    Actor other = (Actor) o;
    return Objects.equals(firstname, other.firstname) &&
           Objects.equals(lastname, other.lastname);
}

//    @Override
//    public int hashCode() {
//        int result = firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0;
//        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
//        return result;
//    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = Objects.hashCode(firstname);
    return 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(lastname);
}

//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        return "Actor{" +
//                "firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
//                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
//                '}';
//    }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Actor{firstname='" + firstname +
               "', lastname='" + lastname + "'}";
}
```

Otherwise, your code looks pretty good.

Hope that helps.